# Special character in SP.UI.ModalDialog option "Title" ignored/not accepted

Tags: form, modal-dialog

I have a question regarding my ModalDialog.

There is an option called title:

```
options.title = 'Benutzer wählen';
```

Now if I display the dialog:

```
var dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

The ä from "wählen" doesn't get accepted by SharePoint, I also tried using:

```
&auml;
```

But that didn't change anything. It was just standing there as plain text.

Comment: If it's an aspx page you are opening, set the title in the code behind of that page.

Comment: even if I'm creating the dialog in my code at runtime?

Comment: did you try encoding the text?
encodeURIComponent("Benutzer wählen"), this will result in 
"Benutzer%20w%C3%A4hlen"

Comment: Not yet! This is a good idea. let me come back to you